# How can I have a method parameter with type dependent on an implicit parameter?

Tags: scala, dependent-type

```
trait JsonOps[J] {
  type ObjectFields
  def partitionObjectFields(fields: ObjectFields, fieldNames: List[String]): (ObjectFields, ObjectFields)
}

def compilerNoLikey[J](stuff: ops.ObjectFields)(implicit ops:JsonOps[J]) = {}

def compilerLikey[J](stuff: Any)(implicit ops:JsonOps[J]) = {
    val stuff2 = stuff.asInstanceOf[ops.ObjectFields]
}
```

You can see my intent here.  I define a type in JsonOps to encapsulate a structure dependant on J.  Then later when I want to use this, I have a function that implicitly passes a JsonOps[J] object and also a parameter of type ObjectFields.

Problem is, ObjectFields is defined in ops, which occurs after the stuff in the signature.

How can I unscramble this?

The second def works, but I don't like passing Any around.  I'd like the compiler to be able to check what's being passed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should introduce one more type parameter for `compilerLikey` and write `JsonOps` with refinement

```
trait JsonOps[J] {
  type ObjectFields
  def partitionObjectFields(fields: ObjectFields, fieldNames: List[String]): (ObjectFields, ObjectFields)
}

def compilerLikey[J, OF](stuff: OF)(implicit ops: JsonOps[J] { type ObjectFields = OF }) = {}
```

or using [Aux-pattern](http://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html)

```
trait JsonOps[J] {
  type ObjectFields
  def partitionObjectFields(fields: ObjectFields, fieldNames: List[String]): (ObjectFields, ObjectFields)
}

object JsonOps {
  type Aux[J, OF] = JsonOps[J] { type ObjectFields = OF }
}

def compilerLikey[J, OF](stuff: OF)(implicit ops: JsonOps.Aux[J, OF]) = {}
```