# Returning a value from a method which must implement a typeclass

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, implicit

I am trying to have a method return a value that must implement a typeclass, and I think it is highlighting to me more generally how I don't understand Scala's generic parameter resolution process. I have a situation something like this:

```
trait IsContainer[A, T] {
  def getOtherContainer[O](implicit tc2: IsUnit[O]): O
}

trait IsUnit[A] { }
implicit val anIntIsUnit = new IsUnit[Int] { }

implicit def aListIsContainer[T] = new IsContainer[List[T], T] {
  def getOtherContainer[Int] = 3
}
```

This is raising a compile error: `Missing implementation for: def getOtherContainer`. My uninformed guess about what should be happening here is that Scala sees I have passed the generic parameter `O`, and considers the method implemented if all instances of the `O` type are consistent. So in this case (since I have explicitly told it that `O` = `Int`, it checks that there is an instance of `IsUnit[Int]` in scope, and that the output type of the method is of type `O`. If this is correct (and I'm not saying it is!) then why is this not working?

More generally, if I skipped the `[O]` generic parameter and let it guess - so I just implemented the method with `getOtherContainer = 3` - should I also expect it work? To infer what `O` should be, does it scan over the line and see if `O` has been concretely filled out in any of the three places it is mentioned, and infer from that?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enforcing that dependent return type must implement typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63803620/enforcing-that-dependent-return-type-must-implement-typeclass)

Comment: @cchantep - haha - that's actually my own question. It sort of does but the solution relies on having defined an abstract type already defined in the trait, which doesn't fit this circumstance perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct is

```
implicit def aListIsContainer[T] = new IsContainer[List[T], T] {
  override def getOtherContainer[O](implicit tc2: IsUnit[O]): O = ???
}
```

Your type class

```
trait IsContainer[A, T] {
  def getOtherContainer[O](implicit tc2: IsUnit[O]): O
}
```

means that if a tuple of types `A`, `T` have an instance of the type class then you know how to do `getOtherContainer` **for any** type `O` having an instance of type class `IsUnit`.

When you're trying to remove `(implicit tc2: IsUnit[O])` or `[O]` in the definition of an instance you're actually trying to violate the contract of type class.

If you want to specialize `O` in an instance (for example `O := Int`) then you should move type parameter `O` to the type class level

```
trait IsContainer[A, T, O] {
  def getOtherContainer(implicit tc2: IsUnit[O]): O
}
```

or

```
abstract class IsContainer[A, T, O](implicit tc2: IsUnit[O]) {
  def getOtherContainer: O
}
```

or

```
trait IsContainer[A, T] {
  type O
  def getOtherContainer(implicit tc2: IsUnit[O]): O
}
```

Then you can define an instance

```
implicit def aListIsContainer[T] = new IsContainer[List[T], T, Int] {
  override def getOtherContainer(implicit tc2: IsUnit[Int]): Int = 3
}
```

or

```
implicit def aListIsContainer[T] = new IsContainer[List[T], T, Int] {
  override def getOtherContainer: Int = 3
}
```

or

```
implicit def aListIsContainer[T] = new IsContainer[List[T], T] {
  override type O = Int
  override def getOtherContainer(implicit tc2: IsUnit[O]): O = 3
}
```

correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is this definition:

```
def getOtherContainer[Int] = 3
```

In this definition, `Int` is a type parameter, not the type `Int`. It is exactly the same as

```
def getOtherContainer[T] = 3
```

So you have not "explicitly told it that `O` = `Int`", you have just used `Int` as the name of type parameter rather than `O`. Since this does not match the required signature in the trait, there is no valid implementation of `getOtherContainer` and you get the error.

Comment: thanks, that's interesting and I didn't realize that at all. So, is it impossible to explicitly pass types to methods as generic parameters? And is there a way to make this example work?

Comment: Types are not concrete values so they cannot be passed anywhere. When calling a method with a type parameter you can specify the type directly (as in `IsUnit[Int]`) or let compiler infer it. But I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, so it is hard to comment further.

Comment: ok, thanks. it's somewhat unclear to me why it's OK to specify the type in `IsUnit[Int]`, but not in `getOtherContainer[Int]` - in both cases it looks like it should be a matter of replacing a generic type parameter with an actual one. If no type is specified - eg if I just use `def getOtherContainer = 3`, does it attempt to infer that `O` should be an `Int`, based on the return type?

Comment: @Chrisper; The difference is call-site / definition-site. The call site is where the type parameter is specified or omitted (i.e. left for the compiler to infer). The definition site is where the type parameter is given a name within the scope of the method being defined. It can be `O` or `T` or `ARabbit` but giving it a name like `Int` will only confuse those trying to read the code.

Comment: @jwvh - Right - that does make sense.