# Confusion about type refinement syntax

Tags: scala, types, structural-typing, refinement-type

On Type Level, i stumble upon the following:

```
sealed abstract class StSource[A] {
  type S
  def init: S            // create the initial state
  def emit(s: S): (A, S) // emit a value, and update state
}

object StSource {
  type Aux[A, S0] = StSource[A] {type S = S0}

  def apply[A, S0](i: S0)(f: S0 => (A, S0)): Aux[A, S0] =
    new StSource[A] {
      type S = S0
      def init = i
      def emit(s: S0) = f(s)
    }
}
```

The line that intrigued me is `type Aux[A, S0] = StSource[A] {type S = S0}`

In paerticular `{type S = S0}` in `StSource[A] {type S = S0}`

I do not really know how to read this, as in interpreting the construct involved here.

What is `StSource[A] {type S = S0}` ??? is that a structural type (part of it looks like it)

When defining type like trait, or class, Is the body of a class part of the type constructor represented by the class itself? what happened to the method in it ?

Really confused. Can someone deconstruct that please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StSource[A] {type S = S0}` is a refined type.  `{type S = S0}` is a type refinement.

From one side, `StSource[A] {type S = S0}` is a subtype of `StSource[A]`.

From the other side, `StSource[A]` is also an existential type with respect to `StSource[A] {type S = S0}`, namely `StSource[A]` is `StSource.Aux[A, _]` (aka `StSource.Aux[A, X] forSome {type X}`).

```
def test[A, S] = {
  implicitly[StSource.Aux[A, S] <:< StSource[A]]
  implicitly[StSource.Aux[A, _] =:= StSource[A]]
  implicitly[StSource[A] =:= StSource.Aux[A, _]]
}
```

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#compound-types

> A *compound type* 1 with … with {} represents objects with members as given in the component types 1,…, and the refinement {}. A refinement {} contains declarations and type definitions. If a declaration or definition overrides a declaration or definition in one of the component types 1,…,, the usual rules for overriding apply; otherwise the declaration or definition is said to be “structural”.

See also examples how to use refined types:

https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/19/forget-refinement-aux.html

[How can I have a method parameter with type dependent on an implicit parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728943/how-can-i-have-a-method-parameter-with-type-dependent-on-an-implicit-parameter/)

[When are dependent types needed in Shapeless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131067/when-are-dependent-types-needed-in-shapeless/)

[Why is the Aux technique required for type-level computations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544660/why-is-the-aux-technique-required-for-type-level-computations)

[Understanding the Aux pattern in Scala Type System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900674/understanding-the-aux-pattern-in-scala-type-system)

[Enforcing that dependent return type must implement typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63803620/enforcing-that-dependent-return-type-must-implement-typeclass)

> When defining type like trait, or class, Is the body of a class part of the type constructor represented by the class itself? what happened to the method in it ?

You can replace

```
def apply[A, S0](i: S0)(f: S0 => (A, S0)): Aux[A, S0] =
  new StSource[A] {
    override type S = S0
    override def init = i
    override def emit(s: S0) = f(s)
  }
```

aka

```
def apply[A, S0](i: S0)(f: S0 => (A, S0)): StSource[A] {type S = S0} =
  new StSource[A] {
    override type S = S0
    override def init = i
    override def emit(s: S0) = f(s)
  }
```

with

```
def apply[A, S0](i: S0)(f: S0 => (A, S0)): StSource[A] {
  type S = S0
  def init: S
  def emit(s: S): (A, S)
} =
  new StSource[A] {
    override type S = S0
    override def init = i
    override def emit(s: S0) = f(s)
  }
```

but there is no sense in that because the type remains the same

```
def test[A, S0] = {
  implicitly[(StSource[A] {
    type S = S0
    def init: S
    def emit(s: S): (A, S)
  }) =:= (StSource[A] {type S = S0})]
}
```

When you add `type S = S0` to the type you provide additional information (that type `S` is specific) but when you add `def init: S`, `def emit(s: S): (A, S)` to the type you don't provide additional information (methods `init`, `emit` being there is clear from the definition of class `StSource[A]`).

Other situation would be if the class were defined as just

```
sealed abstract class StSource[A] {
  type S
}
```

or even

```
sealed abstract class StSource[A]
```

Then

```
StSource[A] {
  type S = S0
  def init: S
  def emit(s: S): (A, S)
}
```

would be a type different from `StSource[A]` or `StSource[A] {type S = S0}` (a subtype of them). It would be a structural type (existence of `init`, `emit` would be checked using runtime reflection). Here

```
{
  type S = S0
  def init: S
  def emit(s: S): (A, S)
}
```

is a refinement but not type refinement.

Unlike `def`s (`init`, `emit`) type members don't have runtime representation (unless you persist them, e.g. with `TypeTag`s) so using type refinement doesn't have runtime overhead.